# Android Asset File not found exception

Tags: android

Can't get file located in assets folder.
Throws FileNotFoundException

Here is my file structure

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/661/poaRTG.png

Here is my code

```
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream myInput = assetManager.open("medDB");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your medDB has any extension? if so, put it like assetManager.open("medDB.sqlite"); 
Your folder structure tells the same. 
So it should be like

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream myInput = assetManager.open("medDB.sqlite");
```

I used this code in my project:

```
private void copyFile() {
        AssetManager assetManager = mcontext.getAssets();
        File f1 = new File(SDCARD_Outer_PATH);
        f1.mkdirs();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open("sample.sqlite");
            out = new FileOutputStream(SDCARD_DB_PATH);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Result is the same. I think medDB.sqlite might be attached to project somehow. But i cant figure how

Comment: Usually, at the first time of use, we copy the asset db to sd cars and use it from there. Dont know how you designed it. This code works for me.

Comment: Copy manually? Im trying to do it with code, but i need to get stream from asset file. I placed the .sqlite db manually in assets folder. Is that the wrong way?

Comment: i think u creat database in out side of tha android and put in Assest folder than in first time when u install app than copy data in sdcard

Comment: @NAveen: But that should work if he does it properly

Comment: so what is problem now

Comment: Yes, i did so. But, to copy in working directory, i need a file, located in assets folder. Thats where i get the exception

Comment: try using AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets();

Comment: @Jithu : Im in activity class, so i think, context is not necessary

Comment: I updated the answer with my working code, check any permission issue and try to check with normal file for copy, if it works, then it should be the problem with db file.

Comment: Thanks Jithu, the code is almost the same. So i will try about other file formats.

Comment: replace the db file with an image file and try the copy functionality. if it works fine, then the problem is with your db file, may be permission issu

Comment: It worked for image file. Now i know, its an issue of db file. But have no idea, why it happens

Comment: @Jithu : I removed the extension from db file and it fixed the issue.